# Split string by MAC address with regex doesn't work

Tags: regex, perl

Code:

```
$_ = "Sample sentence with 00-B0-D0-86-BB-F7 MAC address in the middle";
my ($a, $mac, $b) = 
  split('/([0-9A-F]{2}[:-]){5}([0-9A-F]{2})/', $_);
print $mac;
print "\n";
```

For some reason `$mac` is always empty, and I don't know why.

Comment: Maybe try `[\:-]` -- I think the colon may be a special character in that context.

Comment: What *should* `$mac` contain? It's not clear to me how you intend to group.

Comment: @Kerrek SB there are only 4 metacharacters in character classes: ] ^ - \ and colon is not one of them, so there is no need to escape it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you supply [`split`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/split.html) with a string as the first argument it will split on that string as if it were a regex.

```
split ':', $str;
```

Is really a [DWIM](http://wikipedia.org/wiki/DWIM) of:

```
split /:/, $str;
```

---

So your code of:

```
split('/([0-9A-F]{2}[:-]){5}([0-9A-F]{2})/', $_);
```

Really means

```
split(m[/([0-9A-F]{2}[:-]){5}([0-9A-F]{2})/], $_);
# or
split(/\/([0-9A-F]{2}[:-]){5}([0-9A-F]{2})\//, $_);
```

---

Also you want [`split`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/split.html) to save the value that it matches on, so you want the whole match to be in `()`.

```
$_ = "Sample sentence with 00-B0-D0-86-BB-F7 MAC address in the middle";
my ($a, $mac, $b) = split(/((?:[0-9A-F]{2}[:-]){5}[0-9A-F]{2})/, $_);
print $mac, "\n";
```

---

Since you appear to only use `$mac` you don't have to use [`split`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/split.html).

```
my ($mac) = /((?:[0-9A-F]{2}[:-]){5}[0-9A-F]{2})/;
# or
my @macs = /((?:[0-9A-F]{2}[:-]){5}[0-9A-F]{2})/g;
```

Comment: It is not possible to supply a string as the first argument to split. Check perlfunc, the first argument MUST be /PATTERN/ if it is present. split(':', $str) is a (bad kind of) lazy way of writing split(/:/, $str). Some DWIMery (like converting the first arg to split) should not be there. Sometimes Larry gets carried away :-)

Answer (score 1):

First you need to remove the "'" around the regex, it should not be there.
Then you need to enclose the whole split expression inside parentheses if you want the whole split string as a result.

```
$_ = "Sample sentence with 00-B0-D0-86-BB-F7 MAC address in the middle";
my ($a, $mac, $b) =
split(/(([0-9A-F]{2}[:-]){5}([0-9A-F]{2}))/, $_);
print $mac;
print "\n";
```

Answer (score 1):

This is simpler than a `split`. You can just match:

```
$_ = "Sample sentence with 00-B0-D0-86-BB-F7 MAC address in the middle";
$_ =~ /(([0-9A-F]{2}[:-]){5}([0-9A-F]{2}))/;
print $1;
```

Comment: `($mac) = ($_ =~ /(([0-9A-F]{2}[:-]){5}([0-9A-F]{2}))/);`

Answer (score 1):

If you need just MAC address then

```
$_ = "Sample sentence with 00-B0-D0-86-BB-F7 MAC address in the middle";
/((:?[a-fA-F0-9]{2}[:-]){5}[a-fA-F0-9]{2})/;
print "$1\n";
```

Comment: may I recommend only using `$1` if the match succeeds: `print "$1\n" if /((:?[a-fA-F0-9]{2}[:-]){5}[a-fA-F0-9]{2})/;`

Answer (score 0):

`split` expects a pattern that matches what separates the MAC addresses you want to extract. You don't have MAC addresses separated by other things, so `split` is not the right tool to use here. You want the match operator.

```
my ($mac) = /((?:[0-9A-Fa-f]{2}[:-]){5}[0-9A-Fa-f]{2})/;
```

Or if you want to extract multiple addresses from the same string:

```
my @macs = /(?:[0-9A-Fa-f]{2}[:-]){5}[0-9A-Fa-f]{2}/g;
```

An example of `split` would be:

```
my @bytes = split /[:-]/, $mac;
```

Comment: You need a set of parens for your first example to work `my ($mac) = /((?:[0-9A-Fa-f]{2}[:-]){5}[0-9A-Fa-f]{2})/;`